# copy-item where file name is the computer hostname

Tags: powershell

Having what seems to be a basic problem in Powershell. I am doing a simple copy-item script from a UNC share to the local `C:\` drive. Here is my code:

```
$hostname = $env:computername    
Copy-Item -Path '\\server\share\$hostname.txt' -Destination 'C:\'
```

I can't figure out the syntax to have it retrieve the text file that matches the name of the hostname using the variable. If I put in a statically named .txt file that code works.

What do I have to put around that variable for it to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to replace your single quotes with double quotes like this:

```
$hostname = $env:computername

Copy-Item -Path "\\server\share\$hostname.txt" -Destination 'C:\'
```

Comment: FYI, UNC shares needs to start with double backslash - \\.

Comment: Thanks, I must have removed accidentally when copying the code over. Just corrected.

Comment: You didn't remove it. The double slash was missing from the original question (before it was edited).  :-)

Answer (score 1):

Single quoted strings will not expand variables.  You need a double quoted string e.g.:

```
Copy-Item "\\server\share\$hostname.txt" C:\
```

And in general, you don't need to quote string arguments to a PowerShell command unless you need variable expansion or there's a space in the string.

Answer (score 1):

You could also directly embed the environment variable in double quoted string:

```
Copy-Item "\\server\share\$env:computername.txt" C:\
```